# Unexpected token ) Jquery From Simple JSON Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm attempting to learn how to pull JSON via JQUERY and I wrote a simple script to pull my twitter feed and output to the console log and am getting an unexpected token error ).  I've checked everything and I believe I have closed everything correctly but I'm still pretty new so any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var getTwitter = function(){

    $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40neiltyson",      function(json) {
                    console.log(json); 
                });
};

$('#button').click(getTwitter);

)};
```

Comment: *Off Topic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to close your DOM ready handler using `});` not `)};`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getTwitter = function () {
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%40neiltyson", function (json) {
            console.log(json);
        });
    };
    $('#button').click(getTwitter);
}); // <-- Here
```

Comment: blah! well that makes me feel extremely dumb.  thanks...